# Getting error while creating new task definition on conductor

Tags: netflix, netflix-conductor

I am creating a Worker task on conductor with

> http://localhost:8080/api/metadata/taskdefs

but getting this error

> ```
> {
> "code": "INTERNAL_ERROR",
> "message": "INTERNAL_ERROR - Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token\n at [Source: HttpInputOverHTTP@2179fb[c=323,s=STREAM]; line: 1, column: 1]",
> "instance": "linkez-System-Product-Name"
> }
> ```

my task definition JSON payload is

```
{
   "name": "encode_task",
   "retryCount": 3,
   "timeoutSeconds": 1200,
   "inputKeys": [
      "sourceRequestId",
      "qcElementType"
   ],
  "outputKeys": [
    "state",
    "skipped",
    "result"
  ],
 "timeoutPolicy": "TIME_OUT_WF",
 "retryLogic": "FIXED",
 "retryDelaySeconds": 600,
 "responseTimeoutSeconds": 3600 
 }
```

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Yes I was able to resolve this. I made simple mistake. To create the task we have to send the array i,e [] as JSON not {} while posting new task